# Convert strings in array to objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am receiving an array of strings from a server in the following format:

```
var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange" ];
```

Is it possible to convert this into an array of objects, like below?

```
var fruitsObjects = [
    {
        fruit: "apple"
    },
    {
        fruit: "banana"
    },
    {
        fruit: "orange"
    }
];
```

All the object properties will be the same. Happy to use pure JavaScript or jQuery. I've tried using `jquery.extend` but as this adds unique IDs before each value it's not really fit for my purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) -> `fruitsObjects = fruitsStrings.map(function(fruit) { return { "fruit": fruit }; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange" ];
var fruitsObjects  = fruitsStrings.map(function( val, i ) {
  return {fruit:val};
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(fruitsObjects));
```

```js
    var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange" ];
var fruitsObjects  = fruitsStrings.map(function( val, i ) {
  return {fruit:val};
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(fruitsObjects));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange" ];
var fruitsObjects = [];

fruitsStrings.forEach(function (item) {
    fruitsObjects.push({ fruit: item });
});
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ekeckgvx/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange" ];
var fruitsObjects = [];

$.map( fruitsStrings, function( val, i ) {
  fruitsObjects.push({ fruits: val });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `Array.prototype.map` will do:

```js
var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange"],
    fruitsArray = fruitsStrings.map(function (a) { return { fruit: a } });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(fruitsArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this function where you can specify the key.

```
function toObjects(key,arr) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = arr[i];
    objects[i] = obj;
  }
  return objects;
}
```

```js
var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange" ];
toObjects('fruit',fruitsStrings);
// [{fruit: "apple"},{fruit: "banana"},{fruit: "orange"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
var fruitsStrings = ["apple", "banana", "orange" ];
var fruitsObjects = [];

fruitsStrings.map(function(v,i){
    fruitsObjects.push({'fruit':v});
});

console.log(fruitsObjects);
```

[Working Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/tgkLrx7f/)